# mongodb service doesn't restart after being stopped

Tags: services, init, mongodb

Currently I am unable to start mongodb with the usual command `sudo service mongodb start`. When I do that, I get something like:

```
mongodb start/running, process 23387
```

however no such process is subsequently running, and the mongodb log doesn't show anything new. mongodb DOES however start on reboot, and it can be stopped with `sudo service mongodb stop`.

It's more of an inconvenience than a game stopper, but I'm intrigued - what's going on??

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that `start-stop-daemon` (used by the init script) is aware of other mongodb instances I was running from a command line. When I stopped these instances, I was able to start my main mongodb normally.

A more permanent solution is to [tell `start-stop-daemon` to create a pid file](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/mKrf_BcnTjA) and check it when determining if mongodb is already running. With my default ubuntu install (1:2.0.6-1ubuntu4), the init script only checks if the mongodb executable is running (look for `--exec  /usr/bin/mongod` in `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`).

For the record, [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/mKrf_BcnTjA) talks about this issue and [this quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668810/cannot-start-mongodb-multiple-times-when-using-start-stop-daemon) talks about a somewhat similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Another probability; When we are installing and checking the monggodb by using `sudo`, mongodb directories can be created by 'root' by mistake.

So, check the directories by using `ll /var/lib/mongodb` and `ll /var/log/mongodb` commands.

If the owner appearances as `root` change the owner as `mongodb` by using `sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb -R`

I've experienced!